# Regexp for several URLs

Tags: regex, django

I use this module in Django:
https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

There is setting (CORS_URLS_REGEX) to allow CORS URLs which I cant configure.

I need to combine in one regex:

r'^/api/general/enterpriseinfo/*$' and r'^/api/general/availabletime/*$'

How can I do it?
(Later probably I will need to add other similar URLs in to this regex.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
r'^/api/general/(enterpriseinfo|availabletime)/$
```

Comment: Thanks!
r'^/api/general/(enterpriseinfo|availabletime)/*$'